# Which brushless dc and propeller to choose?

Tags: brushless-motor

I have a small bot(around 4-5kg with wheels) which is to be pushed without contact by another bot. I plan to do this using a bru and a propeller. I am having problems selecting the right combination. Please help me with these questions:-

1. Should the bldc be high kv or low kv(will i need high rpm or low rpm)
2. What is the  ideal propeller to use with the motor so that i can create enough thrust to get the 'small' bot in motion and keep it in motion?
3. What are the other criteria i should keep in mind while selecting.

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns with your question.   Some things that need to be considered include the ease of "pushing" the small bot, which means you need to account for the wheel and bearings being used (can you experiment to determine how much force is required to start it moving?).   Plus you need to know the cross-sectional area which will be exposed to the created wind.  This includes the shape of the small bot plus the angle at which the wind pushes it.   Once you have these, you can determine how much wind is required.   Then start on the fan and propellor selection.

Comment: Instead of an open propeller, try a squirrel cage fan, to get more-concentrated wind.  A "small squirrel cage blower" as shown in  [practicalmachinist.com](http://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/attachments/f33/20498d1266897199-fs-small-squirrel-cage-blower-img_0318.jpg) should work fine.

Comment: @jwpat7 will Electric Ducted Fans be a good alternative?http://www.horizonhobby.com/delta-v-15-69mm-electric-ducted-fan-efldf15

Comment: user6935, a ducted fan produces a more-concentrated windstream, so is good on that basis.  However, for that particular fan, (1) with a thrust of 1.7-2.7 # (0.8 - 1.2 Kg), it will be able to move a 4 Kg bot on a level surface, but not up a ramp, and (2) AIUI that \$30 item is the housing, no motor; and motor is \$65; so \$95+ per fan, which will buy quite a few ordinary props and motors that are cheaper because of large quantities produced for quadcopters.